# Capital Gains on selling a redeveloped house in India

Tags: india, capital-gain, property-taxes

I am an NRI trying to sell my house in India. My house was redeveloped in early 2000s while I was an Indian resident. I got possession of the said flat in around 2006 when I was still an Indian resident.

As far as I have read online, I understand I liable for 20% long term capital gains tax. The 20% is applicable on the gains made where

```
gains = selling cost - purchase price (adjusted for inflation over the years)
```

However my house was "redeveloped" and I just paid registration / stamp duty when the builder redeveloped my existing building and converted it into a 7 storey building.
How do I calculate the purchse price in this situation ?

If I sell the house in 2023 for `1 crore INR` does that mean the capital gains is 20% of the entire sale amount?

Comment: You're asking about taxes in what country? India?

Comment: Yes. Updating the question

Comment: Well if this question is not answerd, i request you to please update here how did you get it done.